# When do we use LIMIT and where clause with ID in SOQL query?

Tags: apex, soql, code-coverage

**This code is working, but I don't understand why are we using The LIMIT and `WHERE Id  =:newstudent.Id`.
if there is only one record I am inserting then why `LIMIT` and use where clause with `ID`.The test fails if I don't use this.**

@testSetup
        static void testData()
        {
               Department__c  newdept = new department__c();
               newdept.name='CSE';
               insert newdept;
        }

```
    @isTest
    static void validateupdatechange() 
    {

       Department__c newDept = [SELECT Id, no_of_students__c FROM 
       Department__c LIMIT 1];

       student_details__c newstudent = new Student_details__c();

       newstudent.Name='From TestClass';   
       newstudent.department__c = newDept.Id;     

       System.debug('before@@trigger: ' + newDept.no_of_students__c);
       test.startTest();

       insert newstudent;

       test.stopTest();

       newstudent = [SELECT department__c FROM student_details__c WHERE Id 
              =:newstudent.Id];


       newDept = [SELECT no_of_students__c FROM Department__c LIMIT 1];
       System.debug('after@@trigger: ' + newDept.no_of_students__c);


       System.assertEquals(1 , newDept.no_of_students__c);
    }
```

Comment: The code is quite simple and so is the question , I feel I have given enough details and the doubt I am having is legit for posting. So if I am wrong in this thinking , please do help me make understand what is wrong with the question i posted atleast before downvoting and leaving with out commenting. Thanks

Comment: Are you using seealldata=true? Because if removing the Id filter causes your test to fail then the test has access to more than one new student record and will error as your property is not a list property

Comment: no i am not using seealldata.

Comment: I think you are getting down votes because you lead off with a long block of code, don't include a ton of information, and don't even specify *how* the test fails. You also have `LIMIT 1` in two separate queries, but don't clarify which one you are asking about.

Comment: But I have seen a lot of other posts where people have longer block of codes, I did state below the code ,test is working fine but i just wanted to know when limit and where id clause is used.both queries are same where the LIMIT is used that's why i didn't specify, I guess people didn't see what I typed below the code where I ask where my doubt was.Next time I'll have to start it before the code I think. Thanks Adrian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id filter simply ensures that the record you want to get back is the one you get.

Without the filter in a test environment when you know only one record exists, the filter is superfluous.

Now, if you remove the filter and get an error something went wrong elsewhere. Either no records or more than one were found if your variable is not a list type.

If removing it causes the test to fail then something is not correct in your code. If you provide the failure or error message and relevant code we could help

Answer (score 0):

If you assumption is correct then I belive that you code should not fail. Also I do not see any instance in your code where you are using `WHERE` clause with `ID=: <XYZ>`.

When you say you are certain that there is only record, are you certain because you are inserting only one record. There may be trigger which inserts a Sub department or a Process or a flow which does the same.

If you are certain that there will be only one record then the test should not fail.

`LIMIT` is used to limit a number of records to a range and it is not really useful to include it while having `where Id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'` as salesforce Ids are guaranteed to be unique. It is useful when you are supplying a list of Ids and using `where Id in ('XXXXXXXXXX','YYYYYYYYYYYYY','ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')`

Also, I do not belive that this query is required:

`newstudent = [SELECT department__c FROM student_details__c WHERE Id=:newstudent.Id];`

Comment: newstudent = [SELECT department__c FROM student_details__c WHERE Id 
              =:newstudent.Id]; , this is the line i am talking about, why is WHERE Id=:newstudent.Id required, because without it , the test fails, also since this is a test class i thought what i am adding is the only data available, since i am only inserting one record i thought only one record is available.

Comment: also about the LIMIT, i understand why it is used, i get confuse is because will it not get only one record, the first record, if i insert 2 records then how will LIMIT help, as we will only be able to get the first record.